# What happened to Ikor?

Tags: marvel

Uatu's father Ikor is the sole reason the Watcher's vowed not to interfere with the affairs of other races, but instead only observe and collect knowledge. The Prosilicans destroyed their planet because Ikor gave them the "gift" of nuclear science which they used to start and finish an auto-genocidal war.

Consequently, the newly-named Watchers left their [home world of T-37X](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Planet_T-37X) with each Watcher choosing a solar system to observe and record for fellow Watchers.

*(from [Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/uatu-the-watcher))*

I am also aware that Uatu left Earth for a time to explore other dimensions looking for a reality in which his father's experiment on Prosilicus did not fail. He obviously cares about his father, so where did Ikor go?